# combobox cascade effect not working for different rows

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2007, filtering, vba

I have two comboboxes on a subform.The first combobox is used to populate the second combobox.  These are placed in the detail section of the form.  I want them to work this way:when I select any value from the first combobox, I want the second combobox of the same row to get populated by relevant value.

As of now, I have tried to implement this and as I select any value from the first combobox of row 1 I see the second combobox of the same row gets populated but as I go on selecting values from the first set of comboboxes I see that the values in the second set of the comboboxes above changing or becoming null.

Here's the code:

The 1st combobox is cboRCMTask:

```
Private Sub cboRCMTask_AfterUpdate() 
    Me.cboRCMTaskOptions.RowSource = "SELECT ID, RCMTaskOptions FROM tblRCMTaskOptions WHERE RCM_ID=" & Me.cboRCMTask.Column(0) & ";" 
    Me.cboRCMTaskOptions = Me.cboRCMTaskOptions.ItemData(0) 
    Me.cboRCMTaskOptions.Requery 
End Sub
```

cboRCMTaskOptions is the second combobox.

The form_current event:

```
Private Sub Form_Current() 
    Me.cboRCMTask.RowSource = "SELECT ID, RCMTask FROM tblRCMTask;" 
    If IsNull(txtRCM_ID) Then 
        Me.cboRCMTask = Me.cboRCMTask.ItemData(0) 
    End If 
    Me.cboRCMTaskOptions.RowSource = "SELECT ID, RCMTaskOptions FROM tblRCMTaskOptions WHERE RCM_ID=" &    Me.cboRCMTask.Column(0) & ";" 
    If IsNull(txtRCMOption_ID) Then 
        Me.cboRCMTaskOptions = Me.cboRCMTaskOptions.ItemData(0) 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

in your first piece of code, shift the code to the on_click event.  I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with the reference to ItemData but I think it is unnecessary, comment out that line.

Similarly the third to last line in the Form_current event, replace with a requery.

Comment: I would not recommend the click event. If this were a single form, the current event and the after update event of combo 1 are the usual for a cascading combo.

Comment: I not only want the 2nd combobox to be requeried but also to display a default value as it is in the detail section of the form.

Comment: @user1175126 Are you using a continuous form? Because none of this is going to happen if you are.

Comment: Yes.The subform is continuous but the main form is single form.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you are using a continuous form. While it looks like a continuous form has many rows, from the point of view of coding you can consider it to have just one row, the current row. I suspect that the control source for combo 2 is a hidden, numeric column in the combo, when you change the row source for the combo, the visible row can no longer be found, so it cannot be displayed. You will either have to provide a pop-up form for editing, or a textbox to store the value for the form and a slightly dodgy combo to edit that value. You can do a little to improve the appearance with conditional formatting.

Comment: The controlsoruce of the second combobox is RCMOption_ID whic is a string.

Comment: I am not sure you are getting the point I am making. You seem to be using a continuous form. When you change the second combo in the current event, you are changing it for **all** rows.

Comment: So what how do I rectify it?Where if not current event?

Comment: What is it about my answer that is not clear to you? You just cannot do this on a continuous form. You **are** using a continuous form, are you not?

Comment: Yes.The subform is continuous but the main form is single form.

Comment: So you have 2 comboxes on a subform and you want them to work as cascading combo boxes, is that right? You cannot do this. When you change combo 2 to suit combo 1 for row *n*, you will be changing it for **all** rows. In my answer I suggest a couple of work-arounds.

Comment: But isn't there a way to bind the combobox to a unique column like ID of the same row?I could not understand what this:"provide a pop-up form for editing, or a textbox to store the value for the form and a slightly dodgy combo to edit that value"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10387/discussion-between-remou-and-user1175126)