# base dropdown on 2 other options

Tags: ms-access, drop-down-menu

I'm setting up a form for students to choose class options.

I have my table, tblOptions,

with 3 fields I want to use; Block, Period, Option Name.

My 'Block' is a text and both the Period and Option Name are dropdown menus.

Is there a way i can get my Options Name dropdown to only return the results of the Block and Period entered into my options form?

Comment: This is called a cascading combo ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588 ) There are problems with cascading combos in continuous forms ( http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+cascading+combo )

Comment: Any recommendations for an alternative?

Comment: There are two reasonable alternatives, I think. You can display records in the continuous form and use a pop-out form to edit and add records. You can display the value in a textbox and have a combo for editing on the same row. This eliminates the problem of the combo being blank in any but the current row, which is disconcerting for users. More notes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274700/combobox-cascade-effect-not-working-for-different-rows/10277823#10277823

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let me take a stab at it...  you want the Option Name dropdown box to only return results that are relevant to the Block and Period on your form.  If I am assuming your form - frmClassOption has the text box txtClassBlock and the dropdowns drpClassPeriod and drpClassOptionName.  You can make the recordset value of the drpClassOptionName to be something like:

```
=SELECT [Option Name] from [tblOptions] WHERE [Block] = [frmClassOption].[txtClassBlock] AND [Period] = [frmClassOption].[drpClassPeriod]
```

My syntax might me a little whacked, but it should go something like that.  Basically, your telling it to only give you options for that dropdown that match your SELECT query that has your previous inputs as criteria.

-- Edited 08/13/2012 @ 1842 hours --

Now that I know it's a continuous form - it begs the question, could you perhaps give a better detail on how you have the forms set up?  Is this a subform of a parent form on which the Block and Period are entered, are the Block and Period Entered on the same form and this is a stand-alone, or some combination thereof?  Could be helpful to narrow down an answer for you.

Comment: I know from a previous question that the form in question is a continuous form, so this will not work from the users point of view.

Comment: This I did not know - I was guessing based on not knowing what kind of form it was.  This method should work for standard forms, though.  Continuous will require something else.

Comment: sorry i should have included that in the description!